# How to open a specific gallery item from a specific fancybox gallery by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So I have made a Fancybox gallery for property pages on a real estate website. This gallery show both property images and a floor plan.

On the property page I have a button to open the floor plan, but how do I open a specific gallery item, which in this case is the floor plan?

This is my code where I find the index of the floor plan gallery item.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var galleryItem = document.getElementById('drawing-item-1');
    var galleryItemIndex = jQuery(".property-gallery__item").index(galleryItem);

    jQuery('.launch-gallery-drawing').click(function(){
        // Open the gallery and display the correct item by the galleryItemIndex
    })
});
```

I have tried using `jQuery.fancybox.getInstance().jumpTo(galleryItemIndex);`, but I think this method is only meant for an open and active instance of a gallery, which it isn't yet.

I have also tried `jQuery.fancybox.open();`, but this creates a new instance/new gallery.

**How do I open a specific gallery item from a specific fancybox gallery by clicking a button?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for `data-fancybox-trigger` feature, see https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage and https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/VGoRqO?editors=1010 for a demo, example:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-fancybox-trigger="preview" data-fancybox-index="3">
 Click me
</a>
```

Comment: You're right! I totally missed the data-fancybox-index attribute in the documentation. Thanks!